# How to get the last Windows domain logon times for all domainusers in Samba?

Tags: ldap, samba, active-directory, login

We run samba as primary domain controller using ldap for the user account settings. As the title says, I am looking for an easy way to get the last logon times for each of those domain users.

I *could* generate a script to lookup all usernames from either pam or ldap and grep the samba log files, which might be error prone. I guess there is already an intended way of doing that.

So, how to get the last logon time for each user on any/all Windows machine(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used samba + LDAP for a while, but I remember there being sambaLogonTime and sambaLogoffTime attributes in the schema.

The [samba-ldap howto](http://download.gna.org/smbldap-tools/docs/samba-ldap-howto/) mentions these attributes

However, I'm not sure if these are populated automatically. [This link](http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2006-January/115883.html) suggests that they aren't, although that's quite old now. I didn't need to use these attributes, so I didn't really pay any attention to them

Comment: This configuration of ldap is a bit outdated, I remember setting up the config via ldif import. As of today there a no sambaLogo{n|ff}Time stamps set (0 and unix_max).

Comment: I think the LDIF in that howto is misleading when it sets those attributes to 0 and unix_max.  Certainly. sambaLogo{n|ff}Time attributes are still present in the schema (I just downloaded 3.5.7 and checked). The second link I posted suggests that these values aren't populated by default, that you need to use a preexec script to update the sambaLogonTime attribute manually.  Not sure what you can do about sambaLogoffTime, but this looks like it meets your requirements at least

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution is to "merge" the machine logfiles and grep for logons

```
grep -A 1 make_connection_snum /var/log/samba/log.* > logons.txt
```

Thus you get the entries for accessing their homedir when logging in.
Sorting by time and user seems like a job for a simple perl script.

Comment: Oh cool a downvote without comment. As that the proposed solution worked for me at that time, I'm curious about the reason.

Comment: `grep -A 1 make_connection_snum /var/log/samba/log.* > logons.txt` should also work and i fixced the downvote ;)

Comment: @djdomi of course, useless use of cat - that happens if you fiddle around a while and take the first solution that works instead of looking at it before posting. fixed now. thanks

Comment: no issue, I cat also instead of grep directly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do realize this is a very very old question. I was in the same position today, and it turns out there is a way to extract this in newer versions of Samba.  (My case was a Zentyal server)

Regardless, what you need is the LDB database which provides the LDAP(-light) that Samba uses for domain authentication.  On my server this was located in `/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb.d/` the file you want is the file named after your Base DN.  So if your base DN is `DC=MY,DC=ORGANISATION,DC=com` then the file would be `DC\=MY\,DC\=ORGANISATION,DC\=com.ldb`.

In order to query the information for a certain user, use their full name using `ldbsearch`.  In my case, if I wanted to find the user Joe SixPack:

`ldbsearch -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb.d/DC\=MY\,DC\=ORGANISATION,DC\=com.ldb  "CN=Joe Sixpack"`

This gives you all known information about the specified user. If you only want the last time they logged on, just specify the attribute:

`ldbsearch -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb.d/DC\=MY\,DC\=ORGANISATION,DC\=com.ldb  "CN=Joe Sixpack" lastLogon`

The format of lastlogon is a "number of 100-nanoseconds intervals that have elapsed since the 0 hour on January 1, 1601 until the date/time that is being stored". I don't really understands what this means, but there is a [Microsoft Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12814.active-directory-lastlogontimestamp-conversion.aspx) that provides a formula for Excel.